# API request saves empty item

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, express

im trying to make a RESTFUL API and when I'm trying to PUT some object and after it, check the DB, the API saved an empty object, even if I've filled the postman key-value things.. Here is my code

[POSTMAN SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Gdz.png)

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var methodOverride = require("method-override");
var model = require('./models/librosModel')
var Libro  = mongoose.model('Libro');
var LibrosCtrl = require('./libros');


// Configuración de la aplicación express
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));  
app.use(bodyParser.json());  
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
console.log('ready');

//CONFIG END

//MONGO CONFIG
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/libros_trading');
mongoose.connection.on('open', function(){
    console.log('Mongoose connected');
});


var usuarios = [];
var sesiones = [];





var libros = express.Router();



libros.route('/libros')
    .get(LibrosCtrl.findAllBooks)
    .post(LibrosCtrl.addBook);

libros.route('/libros/:id')  
  .get(LibrosCtrl.findById)
  .put(LibrosCtrl.updateBook)
  .delete(LibrosCtrl.deleteBook);


app.use('/api', libros);
```

libros.js

```
exports.addBook = function (req,res) {
    console.log('POST');
    console.log(req.body);

    var nuevoLibro = new Libro({
        tipo: req.body.tipo,
        nombre: req.body.nombre,
        descripcion: req.body.descipcion,
        autor: req.body.autor,
        img: req.body.img,
    });

    nuevoLibro.save(function (err,libro) {
         if(err) res.status(500).send(err);
         res.status(200).jsonp(libro); 
    });
    console.log(nuevoLibro.nombre); 
};
```

models/librosModel.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var Libro = new Schema({
        tipo: {type: String},
        nombre: {type: String},
        descripcion: {type: String},
        autor: {type: String},
        img: {type: String},
        creado: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    });
                            //Este es el nombre que recibe en la db.collections
module.exports = mongoose.model('Libro', Libro);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **req.query** instead of **req.body**. Or fill a body in Postman. And delete comma after img: req.body.img.

```
exports.addBook = function (req,res) {
    console.log('POST');
    console.log(req.body);

    var nuevoLibro = new Libro({
        tipo: req.query.tipo,
        nombre: req.query.nombre,
        descripcion: req.query.descipcion,
        autor: req.query.autor,
        img: req.query.img
    });

    nuevoLibro.save(function (err,libro) {
         if(err) res.status(500).send(err);
         res.status(200).jsonp(libro); 
    });
    console.log(nuevoLibro.nombre); 
};
```